# MATLAB - How to change "Validation Check" count

Tags: matlab, neural-network

How can I change "Validation Checks" value from 6 to higher or lower values using code?

I have following code:

```
% Create a Pattern Recognition Network
hiddenLayerSize = ns;

net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);

net.divideParam.trainRatio = trRa/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = vaRa/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = teRa/100;

% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs);

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = targets  .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = targets  .* tr.testMask{1};
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs);
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs);
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs);
```

[image]

I could not find a clue at http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/train-and-apply-multilayer-neural-networks.html

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is not runnable - `Undefined function or variable 'ns'.`. Could you please resolve that?

Comment: That's not the end of it: `Undefined function or variable 'trRa'.`. Please make sure the code is runnable. These problems also prevent me from getting the `nntraintool` window which supposedly pops up automatically when `train` is called.

Comment: Hi! I've made a chatroom for us so we can discuss things related to MATLAB that may be off-topic, or spans longer than what can be placed in a comments box.  Come visit when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DL**: `net.trainParam.max_fail = 8;`

---

I've used the example provided in the page you linked to get a working instance of `nntraintool`.

When you open `nntraintool.m` you see a small piece of documentation that says (among else):

> `%      net.<a href="matlab:doc nnproperty.net_trainParam">trainParam</a>.<a href="matlab:doc nnparam.showWindow">showWindow</a> = false;`

This hinted that some properties are stored within `net.trainParam`. When querying it to see what it holds you get:

```
ans = 


    Function Parameters for 'trainlm'

    Show Training Window Feedback   showWindow: true
    Show Command Line Feedback showCommandLine: false
    Command Line Frequency                show: 25
    Maximum Epochs                      epochs: 1000
    Maximum Training Time                 time: Inf
    Performance Goal                      goal: 0
    Minimum Gradient                  min_grad: 1e-07
    Maximum Validation Checks         max_fail: 6
    Mu                                      mu: 0.001
    Mu Decrease Ratio                   mu_dec: 0.1
    Mu Increase Ratio                   mu_inc: 10
    Maximum mu                          mu_max: 10000000000
```

Here you can see how the **Maximum Validation Checks** is stored: in a field named `max_fail`. Now it was only a case of testing if it was a read-only field or not, which could easily be tested using `net.trainParam.max_fail = 8; train(net,...);` - which correctly changed the default value from 6 to 8.

Comment: Hi! I've made a chatroom for us so we can discuss things related to MATLAB that may be off-topic, or spans longer than what can be placed in a comments box.  Come visit when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab